# Как выделить значение в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой массив:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Его нужно вывести обычным html кодом на страницу, и выделить одно из значений, например arr[2] ==> 3.

И вывести его на страницу что-бы получилось подобное:

```html
[1,2,<b>3</b>,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Как определить, какое значение нужно выделять?

Comment: есть переменная cell = 5 например, значит arr[cell] ==> arr[5] == > 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модификация ответа @Darth:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  pos = 2;
document.body.innerHTML += arr.map((el, i) => i === pos ? `<b>${el}</b>` : el).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6], el = 3;
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arr).replace(el, `<b>${el}</b>`);
```

Comment: var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
массив может быть с повторяющимися значениями, надо делать выбору именно на каком месте находится значение

Answer (score 2):

Заменяете нужный элемент на `<b>el</b>` И выводите массив, при помощи `join()`

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var cell = 5;
var sel = arr;
sel[cell] = '<b>' + sel[cell] + '</b>';
document.body.innerHTML += '[' + sel.join(', ') + ']';
```